# How can access nested JSON objects with this server response

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to parse the response retrieved from a proxied lambda function. I'm using an Ajax call. It fails when I attempt to get the nested Json.

This is the response from the server:

```
{
    "vehicles": "{\"language\":\"fr-FR\",\"id\":\"10107\",\"make\":\"Panoz\",\"model\":\"Roadster\",\"generation\":\"AIV\",\"yearFrom\":\"1996\",\"yearTo\":\"1999\",\"serie\":\"Roadster\",\"trim\":\"4.6 MT (309 ch)\",\"vehicle\":{\"make\":\"Panoz\",\"model\":\"Roadster\",\"generation\":\"AIV\",\"yearFrom\":\"1996\",\"yearTo\":\"1999\",\"serie\":\"Roadster\",\"trim\":\"4.6 MT (309 ch)\",\"id\":\"10107\",\"bodyWork\":{\"rearTrack\":\"Roadster\",\"width\":\"2\",\"cargoCompartmentVolume\":\"4040\",\"curbWeight\":\"1950\",\"length\":\"1190\",\"numberOfSeater\":\"2655\",\"minTrunkCapacity\":\"1700\",\"maxTrunkCapacityLitre\":\"1620\",\"bodyType\":\"Non disponible\",\"height\":\"Non disponible\",\"fullWeight\":\"Non disponible\",\"cargoCompartment\":\"Non disponible\",\"loadingHeight\":\"1160\",\"frontRearAxleLoad\":\"130\",\"permittedRoadTrainWeight\":\"140\",\"payload\":\"140\",\"frontTrack\":\"Non disponible\",\"wheelbase\":\"Non disponible\",\"groundClearance\":\"Non disponible\"},\"engine\":{\"strokeCycle\":\"Essence\",\"cylinderBore\":\"4601\",\"presenceOfIntercooler\":\"309\",\"boostType\":\"de 5 800\",\"valvesPerCylinder\":\"407\",\"injectionType\":\"Distribué injection\",\"cylinderLayout\":\"V-forme\",\"maximumTorque\":\"8\",\"maxPowerAtRpm\":\"Non disponible\",\"turnoverOfMaximumTorque\":\"90\",\"enginePower\":\"90\",\"capacity\":\"4\",\"engineType\":\"à 4 800\",\"numberOfCylinders\":\"Non disponible\"},\"gearBoxAndHandling\":{\"gearboxType\":\"Manuel\",\"numberOfGear\":\"Arrière\",\"driveWheels\":\"Non disponible\",\"turningCircle\":\"5\"},\"operatingCharacteristics\":{\"cruisingRange\":\"95\",\"fuel\":\"250\",\"emissionStandards\":\"13\",\"fuelTankCapacityLitre\":\"Non disponible\",\"accelerationZeroToHundred\":\"4\",\"maxSpeed\":\"de 330 à 430\",\"cityDrivingFuelConsumptionPer100kmLitre\":\"Non disponible\",\"highwayDrivingFuelConsumptionPer100\":\"43\",\"mixedDrivingFuelConsumptionPer100\":\"10\"},\"suspensionAndBrakes\":{\"rearBrakes\":\"Disques ventilés\",\"frontBrakes\":\"Disques ventilés\",\"backSuspension\":\"Sur bras transversaux\",\"frontSuspension\":\"Barre stabilisatrice\"}},\"dateCreated\":1560071289997,\"dateUpdated\":1560071289997}",
    "language": "fr-FR",
    "id": "10107"
}
```

```
var vehicle = JSON.parse(data.vehicles);
                console.log("vehicle: " + vehicle);
                console.log("make: " + vehicle.make);
                console.log("bodyWork: " + vehicle.bodyWork);
```

The instruction vehicle.make returns the correct value.
However when attempting to access the vehicle.bodyWork I receive an undefined answer.

When trying to stringify the data returned, I see the complete correct String. It's as if JSON.parse stopped parsing the first level attributes and couldn't parse the nested objects hence the undefined.

Comment: `vehicle.vehicle.bodyWork`

Comment: The first vehicles has an "s"

Comment: I don't see this question as a duplicate because I obviously try to get access to the nested object as I should. I may be missing a subtlety here.

Comment: "*I obviously try to get access to the nested object*" - which is exactly what the duplicate question is about.

Comment: @SoufianAboulfaouz If you do `console.log(vehicle)` you should see where you went wrong.

Comment: I see now, sorry for the confusion and thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: What @str said... If I run your embedded JSON through https://jsonlint.com/ I can see the nested tree... vehicle.bodywork is not a property that exists.. hence undefined. (PS: you may need to un-escape your \" to " first)

Comment: @SazooCat JSON.parse works without un-escaping, I tried it in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing it wrong, like @str said, the value you're looking for is found at `vehicle.vehicle.bodyWork`. The first `vehicle` stores the entire object, the second has the nested `vehicle` object and that has the `bodyWork` key.